# Get socket's IP address before accepting connection C++

Tags: c++, c, sockets, winsock2

I need to get the IP address of a connection to see if it has already connected previously (checking against a list of ips, if it has connected previously but isnt connected anymore, it will say offline). (using nonblocking sockets)

How can I get the IP without first accepting it.

///

```
    case FD_ACCEPT:
        int W;
        for(W = 0;W <= ListView_GetItemCount(GetDlgItem(HwND,IDC_IPLIST));W++){
```

So then im just gonna check the IP against the list view to see if it had connected before. If it has, I want to use the same socket number it was using last time.

This is how I'm accepting connections right now

```
        case FD_ACCEPT: 
        while(Client[F] != NULL)
        {
        F++;
        }
        Client[F]=accept(wParam,(LPSOCKADDR)&ServAdr,&AdrLen);
        break;
```

so to break it down...

I want to check incoming connections against an IP list of previous connections. This list will have the IP and whether its online/offline (connected/not connected). If it has connected before I want it to show Online when I accept the new connection, and use the same socket number it used last time instead of using a new one all together. If it hasn't I want it to be added to the list. (the list will have the socket number)

If this doesnt make much sense I'll try and clarify a bit more.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Refusing connection from a host](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116225/refusing-connection-from-a-host)

Comment: Of course, this would trash users with NAT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by **socket number** you mean the number returned by `accept()`, you can't rely on it's value at all. I mean, if the remote host disconnects and connects again the value returned by `accept()` will most probably be different. It does not make sense to rely on this number.

If by **socket number** you mean the position in your array, you can assign the value returned by `accept()` to temporary variable:

```
SOCKET tmpSock;
sockaddr_in tmpAddr;
int namelen;
typedef struct { /*...*/ } TClient;
TClient Client[MAX_CLIENTS];
/*...*/
tmpSock = accept(/*...*/);
namelen = sizeof(tmpAddr);
getpeername(tmpSock, (sockaddr*)&tmpAddr,&namelen);
/*...*/
//looking for tmpAddr.sin_addr in your list and calculating
//the list position - F
/*...*/
Client[F].Socket = tmpSock;
Client[F].IsConnected = true;
Client[F].Address = tmpAddr.sin_addr;
```

Have in mind that after the `listen()` call the OS kernel will accept all incoming connection to the port/local IP set by you. It means that the `connect()` of remote host will return successfully whether you call `accept()` or not (provided you have space in listen queue). Calling `accept()` will only allow you to interact with the socket. It will not change the connection state seen by the remote host.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure the is possible nor an efficient specification to achieve what you want. I would either:

1. Accept any connection and then check the IP address, disconnecting connections which are not in the list
2. (This probably isn't suitable for you) Configure an upstream firewall, such that only allowed IP addresses are allowed through.

Comment: Good answer, thank you. In some cases, it may be beneficial/necessary to do both #1 & #2.  For example, if you need to send different data to different clients.

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking for cannot be done with `accept()`. You do not have access to a connection's information until after it has been accepted and a new `SOCKET` handle allocated. To get the connection info pre-acceptance, you have to use the callback functionality of `WSAAccept()` instead.

Either way, there is no way to reuse an existing `SOCKET` handle for a new connection. Each accepted connection must have its own unique `SOCKET` handle.  You can certainly associate the new connection from a previously-seen IP with an existing slot in your ListView, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you bind to a wildcard address (`INADDR_ANY`), then the IP address used for communication isn't determined until a connection comes in (it will be one from the interface the packets are passing through).  The same listening socket can result in accepted connections on more than one IP address.

If you bind to a specific address, then you already know the address you bound to.