# How can I refuse a socket connection in C?

Tags: c, sockets

If I want to accept a connection I call `accept`, but how can I refuse a connection?

In a working socket echo client I have this if statement. In the echo server, how can I make the echo client reach this `printf` statement?

```
...
if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(server)) < 0) { 
    printf("Connecting failed\n"); 
    return 1; 
}
...
```

Comment: accept and close immediately

Comment: @BartFriederichs: that is what I am doing currently, but is there a way to actually refuse it more explicitly?

Comment: Based on what would you refuse? I'd say what you want is the job of a firewall. Most applications I know thta work with blacklisting or such would accept and close.

Comment: Actually I want strictly one connection only on this particular port. Any other connection should ideally fail in a very obvious way.

Comment: just accept only once

Comment: Set the backlog argument to listen(2).

Comment: As @BartFriederichs says, the obvious way is close immediately, another solution is to use `/etc/host.allow` file

Comment: Don't accept at all and close the socket. The client will then trigger the timeout error on connect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Refusing connection from a host](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116225/refusing-connection-from-a-host)

Comment: Pretty useful if you want to implement a TCP liveness probe...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To my knowledge, that isn't how TCP works. The `accept(..)` call will always return with the client details. There is **no way to *peek* at the connection** and selectively refuse.

The way you are doing it now is actually the correct way: accept and then close. In case you have another message structure over and above this layer, you can create a custom "Reject message". This option completely depends on your use case.

In case you are looking for rejecting on the basis of IP address, its not within your apps domain. Its the job of your firewall (As @Bart Friederichs says). That way, the request will not even touch the TCP stack.

---

> Actually I want strictly one connection only on this particular port. Any other connection should ideally fail in a very obvious way.

Do not let the accept call in your control flow. Only when you wait on `accept` will your program wait for a socket connection, never otherwise.

Answer (score 13):

To get the behavior you want (only accept one connection at a time, other clients attempting should get a failure), there are two choices.

- You can close your listen socket after you have accepted a connection. Re-create your listen socket after the accepted connection closes.
- You can close newly established connections if there is already a connection in progress. If you want the client to see a TCP reset, most TCP stacks will trigger one if you enable the linger option with a timeout of 0.

  `struct linger lo = { 1, 0 };`
  `setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_LINGER, &lo, sizeof(lo));`
  `close(s);`

Comment: Is the first option really used in practice? It might be better to keep the listening socket open, to ensure the resource is "owned" by the program for its use as long as it is running.

Comment: @CraigMcQueen: I am assuming server ports have been provisioned if this option is used.

Answer (score 6):

In standard socket APIs on most platforms, there is no way to reject a connection.  You must `accept()` the connection and then close it immediately if you don't want it.

The exception to this rule is the Winsock-specific [`WSAAccept()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741513%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.  It provides a callback that allows an application to decide, on a per-connection basis, whether a connection should be accepted, rejected, or kept in the backlog queue.

Answer (score 2):

It might be helpful

1. to close the listening server socket after having successfully `accept()`ing the client connection and
2. to re-establish it after the client connection has gone due to whatever reason.

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the party, but you can use WSAAccept() instead of accept().  WSAAccept() has an optional callback function that allows you to take a peek at who's knocking at the door and decide if you want to answer.  Your callback function can return the constants CF_ACCEPT, CF_REJECT and CF_DEFER.  The first two are obvious.  The 3rd one allows you to defer answering in case you need to decide later.  Once you've decided for sure you call WSAAccept() again and either accept or reject.

Unfortunately, you have to either accept or reject in order to remove the entry from the front of the listen queue.  The reason I say it's unfortunate is there is an obvious difference to the connecting machine between getting rejected and never getting a response (timeout).

If a hacker is using a port scanner they'll know you're listening on the port if you reject.  At that point they can start hacking their way in.  It would be nice to be able to remove the entry from the front of the queue without ever doing anything with it such that whoever's on the other end doesn't know you're listening on that port.

Comment: It's is so strange that there are no functions for this. I'm creating a web server and was thinking that I should make every banned IP timeout (not open the TCP connection and have my OS free up any info allocated for that incoming connection). But that seems not possible without writing my own OS or network driver? I am thinking that if I never open the connection then the routers will not accept more packets from it as well. Hence I can save some bandwidth in case of DoS.

Comment: A follow up to what I wrote above. Since I'm using Linux I found that the service firewalld can do what I want. I can tell it to "ban" certain IP addresses and to them it will look like I'm not running a server then. And I can interface with this service from my own server :)