# Make TThreadPoolServer refuse further connections when all threads are used

Tags: c++, rpc, thrift

I'm running a `TThreadPoolServer` with a worker count of 4 (for example):

```
using apache::thrift::concurrency::ThreadManager;
using apache::thrift::protocol::TBinaryProtocolFactory;
using apache::thrift::server::TThreadPoolServer;
using apache::thrift::TProcessorFactory;
using apache::thrift::transport::TBufferedTransportFactory;
using apache::thrift::transport::TServerSocket;

std::shared_ptr<TThreadPoolServer> server(
    std::make_shared<TProcessorFactory>(),
    std::make_shared<TServerSocket>(host, port),
    std::make_shared<TBufferedTransportFactory>(),
    std::make_shared<TBinaryProtocolFactory>(),
    ThreadManager::newSimpleThreadManager(4)
);

server->setServerEventHandler(some_event_handler);

try
{
  server->serve();
}
catch (...)
{
  some_event_handler->SetFail();
}
```

Now, when four connections are established and a fifth client tries to connect, it just hangs in its first `TProtocol::read*()` call until an existing connection is closed.

I'd like to detect this extra connection attempt and refuse it, so that the client can show an error, instead of having it idle until it is allowed to connect.

Comment: Somewhere at the heart of the TCP server there will be an "accept" call which, upon receiving an incoming connection on the "listen-socket", will probably start an "IoThread" to handle the "connection-socket".  When you detect the limit, instead of starting the thread, you could simply transmit an error message on the "connection-socket" and close it.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/16591420/1607937