# How can I reject TCP request with Qt

Tags: qt, sockets, tcp, client-server

In Qt5 if we use qtcpSocket->->disconnectFromHost(); that mean i close competely the connection to the distant Host. 
My question is how can i reject a tcp connection ???

Thx all

Answer (score 4):

You can't.  After the passive open(), the OS accepts every connection while your program sleeps.

Answer (score 1):

It's a TCP protocol design question. Once a connection is opened, you can't reject it. You just can closed, if

Detailed explanation in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1117132/721929

Comment: To reject a connection i tried to reject the icmp request from client by answering with" Destination Unreachable". So i create the ipHeader and icmpHeader for client and server. And when client try to contact server he needs to complete the Code = 0 , Type = 0 of icmp package of icmpHeader(Client need to create icmp echo request package). When a package arrive to the server, he answers by another package with (Code=7, Type=3 : it is Destination Unreachable package).

My huge problem is when the client send echo request, i receive in the server EchoReply( I checked by WireShark).

Comment: "If you need to handle incoming TCP connections (e.g., in a server application), use the QTcpServer class. Call QTcpServer::listen() to set up the server, and connect to the QTcpServer::newConnection() signal, which is emitted once for every client that connects. In your slot, call QTcpServer::nextPendingConnection() to accept the connection and use the returned QTcpSocket to communicate with the client." from http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtnetwork/qtnetwork-programming.html. Would it fit your need?

Comment: @MouradKarim If you just need to reject some connections, I don't see how could it be related to ICMP.